# How would I position a dropdown to the left or right of a vertical CSS menu?

Tags: html, css

I've written a basic CSS menu - a vertical nav-bar designed to be placed to the side. However, in addition to it's current design I'd like to be able to place the drop down from item 2.0 to either the left or right of the parent as well.

What would be the best way to accomplish this?

I'm also including a JSFiddle link of the current code: https://jsfiddle.net/eagqxnaz/1/

```
<ul class="navbar">
  <li><a href="#">1.0</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">2.0</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/?">2.1</a></li>
      <li><a href="/?">2.2</a></li>
      <li><a href="/?">2.3</a></li>
      <li><a href="/?">2.4</a></li>
    </ul>         
  </li>
</ul>

.navbar li  {
    width: 150px; 
    text-align: center;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #a1a0a5;
}

.navbar a {                         
    color: #FFF;
    display: block;
    padding: 8px 4px;
}

.navbar a:hover {
    background-color: #5a5775;
}

.navbar li ul {
    display: none;
}               

.navbar li:hover ul     {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    left: 0;
}
```

Comment: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eagqxnaz/2/)

Comment: Thank you - I couldn't quite get that working properly. Please make an answer with an explanation for others?

Comment: You are welcome, Your problem is solved that is enough. However one thing I would like to mention, as a better practice, you shouldn't apply styles on `hover`. Add them to the normal styles and on hover it should be only `display: none / block` unless some style changes are needed on hover.

Comment: Thank you for that - I'll fix it. I was trying to keep it as compact as possible, particularly with the thought of it being seen. Far too many examples of code are all over the place.

Comment: One more thing, If you are willing to place child relative to the parent then add `position: relative` on parent like `li` in your case and `position: absolute` on child with `left: 100%; top: 0` to get the result like in above fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Try having top and left to the "**.navbar li:hover ul**", it will display the values something like below screen shot

[image]

Code:

```
   .navbar li   {
    width: 150px; 
    text-align: center;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #a1a0a5;
    position: relative;
}

.navbar a   {                           
        color: #FFF;
        display: block;
    padding: 8px 4px;
}

.navbar a:hover {
    background-color: #5a5775;
}

.navbar li ul   {
  position: absolute;
    display: none;
  left: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  top: 0;
}               

.navbar li:hover > ul   {
    display: block;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: If it is working then it doesn't mean it is a solution. You have hard coded `left` and `top` positions which is wrong. With this solution placement of dropdown will be incorrect as soon as you will resize window.

Comment: @MuhammadUsman Yes you are correct, But it is just a sample code to make it work. We need to make dynamic logic to set left and top in our script based on menu entries and their depth. That can be based on his scripting language.

Comment: We don't need scripting at all here. Check this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eagqxnaz/3/)

Comment: @MuhammadUsman True and i agree with you. Thank you for update. You can edit my answer if it's fine for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
I think this would be a better solution:

Just update your css as given below :

.navbar {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar li {
  width: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #a1a0a5;
  position: relative;
}

.navbar a {
  color: #FFF;
  display: block;
  padding: 8px 4px;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #5a5775;
}

ul.navbar li ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  display:none;
}

.navbar li:hover ul {
  display:block;
}

Hope this is helpful.
```